# Selecting a pixel coordinate on a sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the clicked pixel location on a sphere. I've used the following code :

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (!Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
            {
                return;
            }
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 50000000, Color.red, 100f);
            Renderer renderer = hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;

            if(renderer == null || renderer.sharedMaterial == null || renderer.sharedMaterial.mainTexture == null || meshCollider == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Texture2D tex = renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
            Vector2 pixelLocation = hit.textureCoord;
            pixelLocation.x *= tex.width;
            pixelLocation.y *= tex.height;

            //This line simply recolours the pixel at the above location to red.
            generator.DebugColorPixel((int)pixelLocation.x, (int)pixelLocation.y);
}
```

The issue i'm having that i also have the following script on the sphere object

```
void Update()
    {
        if (rotate)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        rotate = false;
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        rotate = true;
    }
```

The issue is that if the sphere is allowed to rotate at any point before clicking (as in, the rotationSpeed is anything above 0) the coordinates returned from hit.textureCoord are innactuate. They appear to be offset along the x axis. If the sphere isn't allowed to rotate the coordinate is returned correctly. Using the debug ray i can see the raycast hit's the correct location, But the recoloured pixel is not where the raycast hit.

I'm stumped as to what is causing this.

EDIT: 
As requested the recolour code is:

```
  Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Sphere.materials[0].mainTexture;
    tex.SetPixel(x, y, Color.red);
    tex.Apply();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So it turns out this was my own damn fault. The sphere was a child of an empty gameobject that for some unknown reason i had scaled in the past to be 2,2,1 which caused the sphere to be mis-shaped, which caused these issues!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont avoid the rotation when raycast hits:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (!Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
            {
                return;
            }
            rotate = false;
            //do something with the pixel


            rotate = true;
}
```

Comment: The rotation is already disabled when raycasting due to the onmouseenter. The sphere is NOT rotating while raycasting. Only before and it still offsets the pixel coordinates.

Comment: No, the rotation is in a script on the sphere, The selection is on a script on the camera

Comment: when rotate switch to false, the sphere continues to rotate a little? or stop at once? so the problem is how you recolored the pixel..dont see the code...

Comment: The rotation stops before, as soon as the cursor enters the sphere before you can click.I'll add the recolour code to the OP

Comment: could you test just this. instead to use boolean rotate, set RotationSpeed to Zero when mouseenter and set the right value when mouse exist?

Comment: Same results unfortunatly.

Comment: Ok so i've just created a new project to test a theory. a single script doing all the above on a sphere and it worked fine. The only difference i can see if that my original project was starting in 2D setup and the test one was 3D. I'm not sure how that effects this however.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, see the answer i posted for how i was my own stupid mistake!